# Retornar data completa jQuery PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Boa noite, a idéia é ele retornar a data completa para ser possível buscar no banco de dados corretamente.
Quando abro a página fica assim:
[image: Quando abro a página]

Quando clico no dia seguinte fica assim:
[image: Quando clico no dia seguinte]

Aparentemente correto, porem preciso do ano também para uma busca mais correta no BD.
Abaixo o código de como está ficando:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".b").click(function() {
    $(".b").addClass("a");
    $(this).removeClass("a");
    var novothis = $(this);
    $(".vaipa").text($(novothis).text().substring(5, 10));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="b">
  <?php echo strftime('%a, %d/%m', strtotime('+0 day'));?>
</div>
<div class="a b">
  <?php echo strftime('%a, %d/%m', strtotime('+1 day'));?>
</div>
```

Se alguém tiver uma ideia de como melhorar, agradeço!!

Comment: Adicione %Y ou %y para adicionar o ano.

Comment: eu quero que somente tenha o ano no retorno dado pelo jQuery, pois só preciso dele para buscar no BD, nos botões acima, nao quero mudar aquele formato